# Method to exexute every time a component shows in the screen

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-components

I'm trying to execute a method every time I load a component. My workflow as follows.

- I have a page and in the page e.g. (`List`) I call a component called `selected-options`
- I have a service class that have a counter.

For the first point, here is my code:

```
<ion-item (click)="searchSpecies()">
   Species
  <selected-options></selected-options>
</ion-item>
```

What I want to do is, every time the I access the page `List` the `selected-options` component inside that should call the service and get the latest count.

The problem I'm having is I cannot find the correct method that calls every time the component shows in the screen.

All the methods I've tried seems to be working only for the first time when initializing the component.

E.g. I've tried `ngOnInit`, `ionViewDidEnter`.

What is/are the methods what will call every time the component is called?

E.g. navigating from `List` page to another and coming back to `List` page.

Comment: How is the component added/removed? If it is added by the router you can subscribe to params. I don't know ionic. Without the router in normal Angular the constructor, `ngOnInit()`, `ngAfterViewInit()` are always called when a component is shown.

Comment: hey @GünterZöchbauer, thanks for the comment, I've updated my code with the actual code example. I call the component via html.

Comment: And how is this HTML added?

Comment: `ionViewDidEnter ` should be executed every time the user enters the page (it used to work like that in .beta-11)... are you using the new Ionic2 RC?

Comment: @sebaferreras, thanks for the comment, yes I'm using RC.0.